# Not able to capture Japanese characters from ajax in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am making an AJAX request from one page to another webform (*.aspx). I am passing Japanese text as description from ajax and this is working fine in all browsers except in IE. I even added Japanese language (ja-JP) to the browsers languages with an assumption that IE will support it but I failed.

Need some work around for this... Waiting for your help.

Below is my ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
      url: urlAssetUpload + uploadVars,
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
      data: encodeURIComponent(formDatz)    
    });
```

Comment: Whats the Error you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting "?????" while accessing through queryString. I even tried parsing query string using HttpUtility

Comment: Can you try putting this in  header of your page ?
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: I did that and tried with UTF-16 as well... :(